# Populating a graph from a dictionary using igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I have a dictionary which has the follower-followee information. For example:

```
a --> b,c,d
b --> c,d
c --> d
```

Here it means, a follows b,c,d. b follows c,d. c follows d. I have the following corresponding dictionary:

```
{'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['d']}
```

I want to create a **directed** graph out of this dictionary in [`igraph`](http://igraph.org/python/).

What I am currently doing is:

```
import igraph

d = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['d']}

edges = []
vertices_set = set()
for key in d:
    vertices_set.add( key )
    for item in d[key]:
        edges.append( (key, item) )
        vertices_set.add( item )

# vertices_set: set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'])
# edges: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('c', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]

g = igraph.Graph( directed=True )
g.add_vertices( len(vertices_set) )
g.vs['name'] = list(vertices_set)
g.add_edges( edges )

print(len(g.vs))
print(len(g.es))
```

And this code works as expected. However, it is rather ugly (and most likely slower than it should be) as you can see.

I feel like, there should a faster and/or more pythonic way of doing this. Any comments?

Comment: So, your code works? Might be a better fit for codereview then unless you are more specific about what statements you want to improve and why you feel they need improvement.

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Graph.TupleList`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#TupleList) function:

```
>>> from igraph import Graph
>>> d = {'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['c', 'd'], 'c': ['d']}
>>> g = Graph.TupleList([(k, v) for k, vs in d.iteritems() for v in vs])
>>> print g
IGRAPH UN-- 4 6 --
+ attr: name (v)
+ edges (vertex names):
a -- b, c, d   b -- a, c, d   c -- a, b, d   d -- a, b, c
```